# Bash to transform string `3.11.0.17.16` into `3.11.0-17-generic`

Tags: string, bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to transform this `3.11.0.17.16` into `3.11.0-17-generic` using only bash and unix tools. The `16` in the original string can be anything. I feel like `sed` is the answer, but I'm not comfortable with its flavor of regex. How would you do this?

Comment: Is the trailing "-generic" to be hardcoded, or is some sort of lookup involved?

Comment: It's hardcoded for this one

Comment: Try `echo 3.11.0-17-generic`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version using `awk` instead of `sed`:

```
echo "3.11.0.17.16" | awk -F. '{printf "%s.%s.%s-%s-generic\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

Comment: This is the cleanest imo. Nice. I shouldn't have poisoned the well with the sed suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "3.11.0.17.16" | sed 's/\.\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.[0-9][0-9]*$/-\1-generic/'
3.11.0-17-generic
```

This only accepts digits in the final component.  If you want to accept arbitrary characters other than <kbd>.</kbd> there (you can't allow <kbd>.</kbd> or the match will become ambiguous) then write instead

```
echo "3.11.0.17.gr@wl1x" | sed 's/\.\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.[^.][^.]*$/-\1-generic/'
```

In a portable `sed` invocation you are limited to [POSIX basic regular expressions](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7), which most importantly means you cannot use `+`, `?`, or `|`, and `(` `)` `{` `}` are ordinary characters unless `\`-escaped. Many `sed` implementations now accept an `-E` option that brings their regex syntax in line with `egrep`, but that is not a feature even of the very latest revision of POSIX so you cannot rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

Substring removal using bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) and extended globs

```
shopt -s extglob
version=3.11.0.17.16
version=${version%.+(!(.))}
printf "%s-%s-generic\n" ${version%.+(!(.))} ${version##*.}
3.11.0-17-generic
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you feel yourself tempted to use Bash extensions, instead use Perl or Python.  The *only* remaining virtue of shell is its portability.

Comment: @Zack, you are a man after my own heart, I'd take Python over bash any day but in this case he has not tagged the question with Python

Comment: Sure, sometimes you gotta write a shell script, but then *write a shell script*.  My point is not "Python is a better language than shell" but rather "Don't use bash extensions, because by using them you give up the only virtue of shell (portability) without gaining much of anything compared to what you would get if you just rewrote the whole thing in a genuinely better language (such as Python)."

Answer (score 0):

If you anchor the regex you are trying to match onto the last 3 sets of digits you would get

```
echo "3.11.0.17.16" | sed 's!\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)$!\1-\2-generic!'
```